# Ninject Get<T> WhenTargetHas<T>

Tags: ninject, resolution, contextual-binding

So I'm using Ninject, specifically the contextual binding as follows :

```
Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => FirstBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WhenTargetHas<FirstAttribute>().InRequestScope();
Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => SecondBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WhenTargetHas<SecondAttribute>().InRequestScope();
```

I need to use the Kernel to get a given instance and would like to do it based on the Condition `WhenTargetHas<T>`. Something like the following would be great.

```
var myblah = Kernal.Get<IBlah>(x => x.HasWithTarget<FirstAttribute>)
```

How can you retrieve an instance based on the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Worked out the answer : 
Best to avoid using `WhenTargetHas<T>` instead use `WithMetaData(key, value)`

So

```
Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => FirstBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WhenTargetHas<FirstAttribute>().InRequestScope();
Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => SecondBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WhenTargetHas<SecondAttribute>().InRequestScope();
```

Becomes :

```
 Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => FirstBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WithMetaData("Provider", "First);
 Bind<IBlah>().ToMethod(x => SecondBlahProvider.Instance.GiveMeOne()).WithMetaData("Provider", "Second");
```

You then need to create an Attribute which inherits the Ninject ConstraintAttribute and use that attribute in your constructor arguement.

As :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class FirstProviderConstraint : ConstraintAttribute
    {
             public override bool Matches(IBindingMetadata metadata)
             {
                return metadata.Has("Provider") && metadata.Get<string>("Provider") == "First"; 
             }
    }
```

You then use it in a constructor arg as :

```
public class Consumer([FirstProviderConstraint] IBlah) 
{
...
}
```

Or resolving from the Kernel

```
Get<ISession>(metaData => metaData.Get<string>(BindingKeys.Database) == BindingValues.OperationsDatabase)
```

I need to resolve scoping but that's how you satisfy both Constructor injection and explicit resolution from the Kernel when you have more than one binding.